# How to add a click handler with a modifier to vue-draggable (without triggering choose event)

Tags: javascript, vuedraggable, rubaxa-sortable

I am trying to implement a `click` handler on the child of the `<draggable>` element. I only want the handler to be called if a modifier (alt/ctrl) is used, and I *don't* want the choose event to be called if the click handler is called with a modifier.

```html
  <draggable @choose="chooseEvent">
    <child-element
       @click.native.alt.exact.stop="toggleProblem"
       @click.native.ctrl.exact.stop="toggleProblem" />
   ....
```

This does not work. The handlers *are* correctly called when their modifiers are used, however, the `chooseEvent` *is* always called. If I make the choose event `@choose.exact` that doesn't work either.  I have also tried adding `.stop` and `.prevent` to the click handlers, doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I have a .handle for dragging everything that I am using and I'd like to be able to click it to toggle other functionality, but the event doesn't fire correctly. `<div class="handle" @click="menuOpen = !menuOpen">`

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't @Djave